# Question on the proof of Backwards Induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I have just read the proof of the Bakcwards Induction in [this page](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Backwards_Induction).

In the Proof section it writes,

'...
So from [Set of Integers Bounded Above by Integer has Greatest Element](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Set_of_Integers_Bounded_Above_by_Integer_has_Greatest_Element), $S$ has a greatest element.
However, $P(n)$ holds for $m<n≤M$ and hence $P(m+1)$ holds. ...'.

I'm not sure that I have got the meaning of the second sentence.
What does it mean by '$P(n)$ holds for $m<n≤M$ and hence $P(m+1)$ holds'?

Comment: Notice that $m<n\leq M$ is true for $n=m+1$.

Comment: @drhab It *is* true. But what's the purpose of pointing out that $S$ has a greatest element?

Comment: Essential for usual induction on $\mathbb N$ is the fact that every non-empty subset has a smallest element. If the order is turned around then you are dealing with the dual demand that every non-empty subset must have a greatest element.

Comment: @drhab Umm, subset of what? $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: In general if $(S,\leq)$ is a well-order then you can apply induction on it. This because every non-empty subset of $S$ has a smallest element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sentence missing from the page you refer to.  After saying that $S$ has a greatest element, it should say "Let $m$ be the greatest element of $S$."

Comment: Your deduction makes perfect sense. Meanwhile it leaves out $n=m+1$, I suppose?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it leaves out."  Since $m$ is the largest element of $S$, $m+1 \notin S$.  And since $m < M$, $m+1 \le M$.  There are actually two possibilities to be considered here: either $m+1 < M$ or $m+1 = M$.  But both lead to the conclusion that $P(m+1)$ is true.  If $m+1 < M$ then $m+1 \notin S$ implies that $P(m+1)$ is true, and if $m+1 = M$ then $P(m+1)$ is true because $P(M)$ is true.

Comment: By the way, I see that the Proof Wiki page has been updated to add the missing step.

Comment: First, I mean "not include/miss sth'' by "leave out".(As I'm not a native speaker, it may sound unnatural) And what you concluded is right, exactly the same as I thought. My question is "is it $n=m+1$ that is missing'', or it could be anything else?
Lastly, the $\mathsf{Pr} \infty \mathsf{fWiki}$ page was edited by me. So if my supposition has something wrong just point it out.

Comment: I just visited the page and fount it is improved again. It is true that $P(n)$ holds for every $n$ which is greater than $m$ and smaller than or equal to $M$. Thanks for your answer anyway! I won't be aware that something might be missing without your answer.